# Comma in number with decimal point in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to put comma in numbers for `varchar` type with single decimal point with no roundup.

For example:

```
DECLARE @val varchar(50) = '12345.999'
```

I want result as :

```
12,345.9
```

So far I have tried:

```
select convert(VARCHAR(15), cast(@val as money), 1)
```

Result: `12,346.00`

but it is doing rounding the value.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to round down to one decimal place, you'd probably need to do some function where you cast the value * 10 as an int, then divide it by 10.0 before casting it as money. e.g. `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),CAST(CAST(@val * 10 AS INT) / 10.0 AS MONEY),1)`

Comment: What will this data be used for?  There may be better options available if we know its purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will work. Just use the `LEFT()` function a couple of times after casting to `MONEY` and `VARCHAR`

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(50) = '12345.99999'

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),CAST(LEFT(@val,
                     CHARINDEX('.',@val,1)+1) AS MONEY),1),CHARINDEX('.',@val,1)+2)


Result:
12,345.9
```

** **Edit** **

After thinking about the possibility of having a larger number for the variable, it wouldn't work when there are multiple commas i.e., 123,412,345.999 so I'm editing to include a `CASE` statement:

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(50) = '123412345.99999'

SELECT LEFT( CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),   
                      CONVERT(MONEY 
                                ,LEFT(@val,  CHARINDEX('.',@val,1)+1)  
                              ,1)
                     ,1)
            , CHARINDEX('.',@val)+(CASE 
                                   WHEN LEN(LEFT(@val, CHARINDEX('.',@val)-1))>6 THEN 3 
                                   ELSE 2 
                                   END))
```

Comment: Hi @bjones, Can I know same for format() in 2012? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @val varchar(50) = '12345.999'

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),CAST(@val AS MONEY),1),CHARINDEX('.',@val)-3) + SUBSTRING(@val,CHARINDEX('.',@val)-3,5)
```

Comment: bjones wins. I think we came up with nearly the identical answer 2 minutes apart.

Comment: Hi DaveX, your is also worked. and also Can I know same for format() in 2012? Thanks.